# Post a comment on a Youtube video externally?

Tags: php, youtube, comments

I am trying to look for a way to post a comment on a youtube video from my (in-construction) website. I am able to get the comments that the users have posted on the video through the use of XML, but was wondering how to enable users from my website to comment on the embedded video that they are watching without having to go to the Youtube website?

I am currently using PHP to do all the processing within my website of getting the embedded video's url, recommended videos, and user comments, but am open to try other languages.

Answer (score 1):

YouTube has an API, and [explicit direction on using PHP to access it.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php#Using_community_features).